# How to get iPhones current orientation?

Tags: objective-c, accelerometer

Is there a special method to get iPhones orientation? I don't need it in degrees or radians, I want it to return an UIInterfaceOrientation object. I just need it for an if-else construction like

```
if(currentOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||currentOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
//Code
}  
if (currentOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight ||currentOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ) {
//Code
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 118, accepted):

This is most likely what you want:

```
UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
```

You can then use system macros like:

```
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation))
{

}
```

If you want the device orientation use:

```
UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
```

This includes enumerations like `UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp` and `UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown`

Comment: This is technically wrong, you're getting a UIDeviceOrientation from your method call and storing it in a UIInterfaceOrientation. A UIInterfaceOrientation is one of the 4, and represents what your interface looks like. The UIDeviceOrientation is one of 6 (includes laying flat and laying flat upside down) and tells you the orientation of the device, not necessarily what your interface looks like. Your interface could be in portrait mode but if the device is sitting on a table it would return UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp.

Comment: @CoryImdieke: Thanks for updating the difference between the device & interface orientation.    UIInterfaceOrientation currentOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];  is the correct API

Comment: This technically is wrong I agree with @Cory but does work quite well. I will post below a method that will not give errors and is the same concept.

Comment: This works well for times when you don't want the interface to change orientation but at the same time you want orientation feedback without having to use the gyro.

Comment: `statusBarOrientation ` is now deprecated.

Comment: deprecated? what to use then?

Comment: Deprecated since iOS 9. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623026-statusbarorientation

Answer (score 11):

As discussed in other answers, you need the interfaceOrientation, not the deviceOrientation.

The easiest way to get to this, is to use the property interfaceOrientation on your UIViewController. (So most often, just: self.interfaceOrientation will do).

Possible values are:

```
UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait           = UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,
UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown = UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft      = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight     = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft
```

Remember: 
Left orientation is entered by turning your device to the right.

Comment: Too bad it is now deprecated.

Comment: Yeah this is deprecated, what do we do now?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a snippet of code I hade to write because I was getting wierd issues coming back into my root view when the orientation was changed .... I you see just call out the method that should have been called but did seem to be .... this works great no errors

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft){
        //do something or rather
        [self 
shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
        NSLog(@"landscape left");
    }
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
        //do something or rather
        [self 
shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
        NSLog(@"landscape right");
    }
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){
        //do something or rather
        [self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
        NSLog(@"portrait");
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work for `UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp` and `UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown`

Answer (score 1):

`UIInterfaceOrientation` is now deprecated, and `UIDeviceOrientation` includes `UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp` and `UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown` so can't be relied on to give you the interface orientation.

The solution is pretty simple though

```
if (CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds) > CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds)) {
    // Landscape
} else {
    // Portrait
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `[UIApplication statusBarOrientation]` being deprecated you should now use:

```
UIWindowScene *activeWindow = (UIWindowScene *)[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] firstObject];

UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [activeWindow interfaceOrientation] ?: UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
```