# What is the best way to get the current orientation for setting views

Tags: iphone, ios, uidevice

I want to detect the current orientation for setting the view, 
which will be the better way for it from the below methods and how ?

`[[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation]`

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]`

Comment: Possibly duplicate question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518695/how-to-get-iphones-current-orientation

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559652/how-do-i-detect-the-orientation-of-the-device-on-ios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]` to detect device orientation.

This method returns orientation value for all cases but if you use

`[[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation]`

sometimes you get unknown orientation.

I hope that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code:

```
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]))
{
     NSLog(@"-Landscape");
}
 else 
{
     NSLog(@"-Portrait");
}
```